# Elements repeated on a php array from sql

Tags: java, php, sql, arrays, select

I have two arrays: in one i inserted all the  Questions ID's from my SELECT and in the other array i want insert the sames ID'S but NON repetead this time. My code in the second array don't works and i don't know why. I can't use DISTINCT in my SELECT because don't works (rows are diferents) and i don't wanna use two selects for this.

```
 $query_slidersanswers= "SELECT A.QuestionIDFK, A.AnswerIDPK, A.AnswerValue, A.SortOrder
                        FROM tblquestionset AS QS
                          INNER JOIN tblquestion AS Q ON QS.QuestionIDFKPK = Q.QuestionIDPK
                          INNER JOIN tblanswer AS A ON Q.QuestionIDPK = A.QuestionIDFK
                        WHERE QS.QuestionSetIDPK = '0' 
                          AND QS.OnPage = '1' 
                          AND Q.Constructor = '".$_session['slider']."'";


$Query_Sliders= mysql_query($query_slidersanswers);         

$currentQuestionID= 0;
while($row_Slider=mysql_fetch_array($Query_Sliders)){

    $QuestionID=$row_Slider['QuestionIDFK'] ;
    $AnswerID=$row_Slider['AnswerIDPK'] ;
    $AnswerValue=$row_Slider['AnswerValue'] ;
    $SortOrder=$row_Slider['SortOrder'] ;


   $tableslidersqid[] = array($QuestionID);

   if($QuestionID != $currentQuestionID){
   //I DO THIS FOR OBTAIN other array with THE UNIQUES ID'S (non repeated)

    $tableslidersREALqid[] = array($QuestionID);
    $CurrentQuestionID = $QuestionID;

    }
}
```

Comment: you can try GROUP BY A.QuestionIDFK

Comment: i dont want change the select , i need both arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your array for question id is as below

```
$input = array( "19", "55", "19", "55", "78" );
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 19
   [1] => 55
   [4] => 78
)
```

**array_unique($array)** will detect the same values in the array and only give the first occured value, rest are skipped.

**EDITED :**

```
while($row_Slider=mysql_fetch_array($Query_Sliders)){

   $QuestionID[]=$row_Slider['QuestionIDFK']; //used $QuestionID[], instead of $QuestionID

   //$AnswerID=$row_Slider['AnswerIDPK'] ;
   //$AnswerValue=$row_Slider['AnswerValue'] ;
   //$SortOrder=$row_Slider['SortOrder'] ;


  //$tableslidersqid[] = array($QuestionID);

  //if($QuestionID != $currentQuestionID){
     //$tableslidersREALqid[] = array($QuestionID);
     //$CurrentQuestionID = $QuestionID;
  //}
}

$result = array_unique($QuestionID); //make array unique here, after all the ids are in the array
```

Comment: I like your idea but i dont no why dont works , if i put $tableslidersREALqid[] =array_unique($tableslidersqid); out of the while only insert the first , and if i put $input = array($QuestionID); inside of the while and after (out) : tableslidersREALqid[] =array_unique($input); dont works too,only inserted the last.why?

Comment: i have edited my code using your codes. I have used $QuestionID[].

Comment: I've seen it . Now i understand why dont works with my code. Thanks!